# How to focus on the selected object?

Tags: 3d-view, objects, shortcut

In Maya if we have an object selected and we press <kbd>F</kbd> then the object is brought into focus and if no object is selected then all the objects in the scene are brought into focus.

How can this be done in Blender?

Comment: I don't have the reputation to add an answer yet - but for me the backtick key: ` opens a 'View' menu that has an option to 'View Selected' which frames the selected object / verts / faces / etc. I'm on a Mac laptop using a trackpad so the numpad and middle mouse button aren't options.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Without knowing the specifics of the Maya feature, try pressing <kbd>.</kbd> on the your keyboard's numeric keypad. This adjusts your 3D View to focus on the selected object. You can also press <kbd>/</kbd> on the numeric keypad to get a "local view" of the selected object (pressing <kbd>/</kbd> again will pop you back to the scene view).

To show all non-hidden objects in the 3D View, press <kbd>Home</kbd>.

For purposes of remapping, this keymap is called *Frame Selected* under *3d View*.

Comment: I don't have a numeric keypad

Comment: @neckTwi, if you're using a laptop keyboard, there's often a Function key that enables a virtual numpad within the body of your main keyboard. However, you're working on a traditional USB or bluetooth keyboard that doesn't have a numpad, your options are more limited. In that case, your only option (outside of getting a new keyboard) is to remap the zoom and focus feature to another key.

Comment: I am on Mac. Ctrl + scroll is doing the thing. Thank you as I found it in key mappings.

Comment: I found camera navigation in the view menu

Comment: What's the opposite of the `Home` function? To rotate the camera without focus on the center?

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman, I'm not sure I fully understand your question. Are you just asking what "might be" an opposite of the Home behavior or are you asking how to specifically do that?

Comment: `.` period does nothing.  Yes, my object is selected.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 `.` (decimal point) key on the numeric keypad (not the period key that's next to the comma key.)

Comment: For the poor users without a numpad: View (in the top menu)/Local View/Toggle Local View

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 In my keypad configuration (abnt2) it is `,`

Comment: Came here for the property name for remapping, stayed for the / which I didn't know about

Answer (score 40):

<kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to zoom to selected (or menu *View > Align View > View Selected*)

<kbd>A</kbd> to select all (you may need to hit it twice), then <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> will zoom to all objects.
Or use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to reset view and recenter cursor.

For purposes of remapping, this keymap is called *Frame Selected* under *3d View*.

Comment: In newer versions of Blender, it's View > Frame selected

Answer (score 24):

In Blender v2.81, hold the alt button and click with the middle mouse button to change centre of focus.

Comment: why minuses? this is the most useful answer!

Comment: This centers the view on the clicked point, not the selected object.

Answer (score 22):

Another option is using the [**Zoom Border**](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#zoom-border) tool (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, then <kbd>LMB</kbd>) to specify a 'rectangular area' of the [**3D View**](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html) and zoom in so that the region fills the actual viewport.

Answer (score 14):

You can add your own hotkey for it:

*File > Preferences > Input > 3D View > 3D View (Global)*

Scroll to the bottom of the 3d view section and click "Add New". The command is `view3d.view_selected`

Answer (score 7):

This functionality, called *Frame Selected* in the system is also available in the View radial menu <kbd>~</kbd> on the bottom right.

Comment: With this, `~` then `S` to snap to object

Comment: This is the answer for me. Why isn't this higher ? This radial menu is clear and fast to use.

Answer (score 2):

Using OS X in French, when I'm in 3D view and I want to Toogle to Local View with the selected object I can do:

*View > Local View > Toggle Local View* (in that menu I can see that the shortcut is `Numpad /`)

So if I have a Numpad I can press `Numpad /` (not the same as `/`)

But if I don't have a Numpad a solution is to change the shortcut.

For changing the shortcut I can do:

*Edit > Preferences > Keymap > Key-binding*

set Filter to `Numpad /` (for local view)
or to `Numpad .` (if you want to change the shortcut for frame selected)

*3D View > Local View* click on `Numpad /` or click on `Numpad .` and choose your own shortcut

Comment: You don't need to have a keypad to use the "/" hotkey. Smaller keyboards have it too. (it should be the "?" key)

Comment: @RandomPanda Sorry but "/" or "?" are not focussing to the object. For that I had to  change the shortcut as I mentioned.

Comment: Blender automatically zooms-in/focuses on the selected-object when you press "/" OR "."; my statement still stands. Sorry.

Comment: @RandomPanda Your insistance surprised me because what you say was not possible with my computer (MacBook Pro with osX in French). So I switched the keyboard to "Américain" and now using the American keyboard what you said is right. So I edited my answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you press <kbd>N</kbd> to access the right side menu, turn on *Lock camera to view*, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to set camera to the current view angle, the press <kbd>Numpad 0</kbd> to view and work in camera view it works better.

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> to view full width of the window. Took me a long time and many frustrations to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I added my own settings for view because I do not have a number pad either. i.e. instead of "numpad 7" I used just "7". I set all of the view and focus shortcuts to this, and it has worked fine ever since.

Comment: `Numpad 7` is just a shortcut to switch into Top/Ortho, How to **focus the selected object** (q here) if you are in Top/Ortho? Also you can simply activate *Emulate Numpad* in *Preferences > Input* in order to re-map `Numpad 7` to `7`, no need for custom settings.

Answer (score -1):

To use number pad without having one, go to *Edit → Preferences... → Input → Keyboard* check the *Emulate Numpad* box

Comment: And how to focus the object when *Emulate Numpad* is enabled?