# control the speed of camera navigation (camera view)

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/navigation.html

I have small object because i set the object size to realistic size just like the size of it in real life. Now my camera move too fast , it pan too fast , roll too fast , zoom too fast even with precision zoom (ctrl + mmb). I have yet to find a documentation on blender on how to control the view speed.

How do i make the view movement slower ?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution . It turns out all that needed is to focus the  view to the selected object.
[How to focus on the selected object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6735/how-to-focus-on-the-selected-object)

First , go to object mode and select the object , then view > align view > view selected . The camera navigation speed will return to normal.

To deal with small part of a large object where the view move too fast , go to edit mode and select at least one faces of the small part , then focus the view , now the camera speed no longer move too fast.

The same method is applicable if the camera move too slow (eg : switching from small object to large object) , simply refocus to the new object or mesh and camera speed will return to normal.

Here are the gif showing the problem and the solution. My blender version is 2.79 , blender UI might be different for blender 2.8x and newer , but the solution is still the same .

It is a very long gif , watch until the end.

https://ibb.co/6Prcykj

[image: gif]